# how to implement control events in wpf using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a slider control in view i need to call the `ValueChanged` event of slider and update one property in model based on that. how i can implement this using MVVM pattern. 
where I have to write the `ValueChanged` event? how i can connect `ValueChanged` event code with view?

Answer (score 1):

i just take the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel) cause i use it in my projects too:

You should use an EventTrigger in combination with InvokeCommandAction from the Windows.Interactivity namespace. Here is an example:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but Interaction.Triggers is not found in my application. is it required to add any other dll files?

Comment: its the Windows.Interactivity namespace and comes from the Blend SDK  - System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

Comment: here is the download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10801

Comment: The link you provided is for framework 4. am using framework 3.5 so i installed blend 3 sdk. but still i have not found exception.

Comment: sorry i really dont know if its in the .net3.5 sdk from blend :(