# How to bind multiple commands on the same control?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Let's say we have a control (a Button). This button is just thrown inside a grid in the most laziest way possible. The Command property is already binded, and it pops a MessageBox. I want to write a second command for my Button, let's say when Mouse enters it's surface (MouseEnter). But I want to do it this way

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyClick}" MySecondCommand= "{Binding MouseHoovering}"
        Margin="34,39,0,0">
```

I know that ICommandSource forces me to implement Command property. As it is already implemented by ButtonBase and exposed in my example. What shoud I do to make "MySecondCommand" possible ? Just to declare it as a dependency property is not enough! :)

Comment: You need `Interactivity triggers`. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel).

Comment: You dont need necessarly a third party blend dll such as Interactivity to do this. You can create attached properties of type ICommand and attached them to your control. However Interactivity will also work and is the "drag it and it works" way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding two commands to one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803913/binding-two-commands-to-one-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your project --> CommandBehaviorBinding.cs,CommandBehavior.cs

use like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyClickCommand}"
    Margin="34,39,0,0"  local:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseHoovering"  
                    local:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding MouseHooveringCommand}">
```

CommandBehaviorBinding.cs:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace yournamespace
{
 public class CommandBehaviorBinding : IDisposable
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the owner of the CommandBinding ex: a Button
        /// This property can only be set from the BindEvent Method
        /// </summary>
        public DependencyObject Owner { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The event name to hook up to
        /// This property can only be set from the BindEvent Method
        /// </summary>
        public string EventName { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The event info of the event
        /// </summary>
        public EventInfo Event { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the EventHandler for the binding with the event
        /// </summary>
        public Delegate EventHandler { get; private set; }

        #region Execution
        //stores the strategy of how to execute the event handler
        IExecutionStrategy strategy;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a CommandParameter
        /// </summary>
        public object CommandParameter { get; set; }

        ICommand command;
        /// <summary>
        /// The command to execute when the specified event is raised
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return command; }
            set
            {
                command = value;
                //set the execution strategy to execute the command
                strategy = new CommandExecutionStrategy { Behavior = this };
            }
        }

        Action<object> action;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Action
        /// </summary>
        public Action<object> Action
        {
            get { return action; }
            set
            {
                action = value;
                // set the execution strategy to execute the action
                strategy = new ActionExecutionStrategy { Behavior = this };
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion

        //Creates an EventHandler on runtime and registers that handler to the Event specified
        public void BindEvent(DependencyObject owner, string eventName)
        {
            EventName = eventName;
            Owner = owner;
            Event = Owner.GetType().GetEvent(EventName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (Event == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Could not resolve event name {0}", EventName));

            //Create an event handler for the event that will call the ExecuteCommand method
            EventHandler = EventHandlerGenerator.CreateDelegate(
                Event.EventHandlerType, typeof(CommandBehaviorBinding).GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), this);
            //Register the handler to the Event
            Event.AddEventHandler(Owner, EventHandler);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the strategy
        /// </summary>
        public void Execute()
        {

            strategy.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }

        #region IDisposable Members
        bool disposed = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters the EventHandler from the Event
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                Event.RemoveEventHandler(Owner, EventHandler);
                disposed = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}



CommandBehavior.cs  :




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace yournamespace
{
  public  class CommandBehavior
    {

        #region Behavior

        /// <summary>
        /// Behavior Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Behavior", typeof(CommandBehaviorBinding), typeof(CommandBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((CommandBehaviorBinding)null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Behavior property. 
        /// </summary>
        private static CommandBehaviorBinding GetBehavior(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (CommandBehaviorBinding)d.GetValue(BehaviorProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Behavior property.  
        /// </summary>
        private static void SetBehavior(DependencyObject d, CommandBehaviorBinding value)
        {
            d.SetValue(BehaviorProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Command

        /// <summary>
        /// Command Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ICommand)null,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Command property.  
        /// </summary>
        public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (ICommand)d.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Command property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
        {
            d.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the Command property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandBehaviorBinding binding = FetchOrCreateBinding(d);
            binding.Command = (ICommand)e.NewValue;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Action

        /// <summary>
        /// Action Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Action", typeof(Action<object>), typeof(CommandBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Action<object>)null,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnActionChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Action property.  
        /// </summary>
        public static Action<object> GetAction(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (Action<object>)d.GetValue(ActionProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Action property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetAction(DependencyObject d, Action<object> value)
        {
            d.SetValue(ActionProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the Action property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnActionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandBehaviorBinding binding = FetchOrCreateBinding(d);
            binding.Action = (Action<object>)e.NewValue;
        }

        #endregion

        #region CommandParameter

        /// <summary>
        /// CommandParameter Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandParameterChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the CommandParameter property.  
        /// </summary>
        public static object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (object)d.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the CommandParameter property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            d.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the CommandParameter property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnCommandParameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandBehaviorBinding binding = FetchOrCreateBinding(d);
            binding.CommandParameter = e.NewValue;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event

        /// <summary>
        /// Event Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EventProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Event", typeof(string), typeof(CommandBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)String.Empty,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEventChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Event property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates ....
        /// </summary>
        public static string GetEvent(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (string)d.GetValue(EventProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Event property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates ....
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetEvent(DependencyObject d, string value)
        {
            d.SetValue(EventProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the Event property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnEventChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandBehaviorBinding binding = FetchOrCreateBinding(d);
            //check if the Event is set. If yes we need to rebind the Command to the new event and unregister the old one
            if (binding.Event != null && binding.Owner != null)
                binding.Dispose();
            //bind the new event to the command
            binding.BindEvent(d, e.NewValue.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helpers
        //tries to get a CommandBehaviorBinding from the element. Creates a new instance if there is not one attached
        private static CommandBehaviorBinding FetchOrCreateBinding(DependencyObject d)
        {
            CommandBehaviorBinding binding = CommandBehavior.GetBehavior(d);
            if (binding == null)
            {
                binding = new CommandBehaviorBinding();
                CommandBehavior.SetBehavior(d, binding);
            }
            return binding;
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent ! I like your post.

Comment: IExecutionStrategy, CommandExecutionStrategy, ActionExecutionStrategy, EventHandlerGenerator are missing some namespaces. Where are they coming from ?