# Populate ComboBox from code behind to display in MyComboBox

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have following in Silverlight xaml:

```
<UserControl........
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="images/Bild1.png" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
    .............
 </UserControl>
```

And in code behind:

```
  static Dictionary<string, string> dictDocTypes
```

which I populate with some Data.
How to show that Data inside the MyComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1**
Put loaded event on your combo. In that typecast sender to ComboBox and populate your data in it.

**Way 2 (Pure MVVM)**

Attach command to event. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel). Pass self (Combo) in it. In VM command, typecast parameter object to Combo and populate it.

Comment: Do you have any example with the loaded event? I dont see MyComboBox in code behind. maybe because is inside a ListBox? Thank you

Comment: When combo is loaded its loaded event will be fired. In the event parameters, sender will be ComboBox boxed as Object. Unbox it and you will get combo. Then fill it.

Comment: Read Michael.Laterza answer in this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/243f5e93-9ebc-403e-be83-a33f4245b66c/wpf-combobox-loaded-event-handling-globally?forum=wpf