# How to open/close view from the XAML code of another view when specific event is risen?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, event-triggers

How to open/close view from the XAML code of another view (using MVVM) when specific event is risen?

Comment: Crete an attached property that can wire up the event to a command from the model.

Comment: Or steal the one from System.Windows.Interactivity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897897/424129

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an event, why not use a variable with DataTriggers?

Have a MainView that has a ContentControl with Content equal to your initial view. Then when you change a variable (for example, from true to false) your MainView sets its Content equal to your other view.