# wpf bind event or command to function on item data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some WPF code that looks like this

C#

```
namespace ItemEventTest
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Otto" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Dag" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Karin" });

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
        set
        {
            m_name = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void WhenMouseMove()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
 }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ItemEventTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemEventTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I now want to do is when the mouse moves over an item is to call `WhenMouseMove` on the object that is the source of that item.
I would like to have the function called directly on the object and not by first going through `MainWindow` or some view model connected to `MainWindow`. It feels like it should be possible because the data is bound that way but I haven't managed to find a description of how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Binding UI events to commands in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel)

Comment: @Hampus Let me understand. You want to do the stuff contained in WhenMouseMove when the mouse enter in a control?

Comment: @DanieleSartori No, when the mouse moves while being inside a ListBoxItem

Comment: What do you mean by "not by first going through"? You need to to write some code that calls the call WhenMouseMove method somewhere.

Comment: @mm8 I'm trying to not clutter up the code behind or the if I had a model view, that with event handlers that do the figuring out what the data context of the item that triggered the event and then calling that

Comment: How are you supposed to be able to call your method if you don't write some code that calls it?

Comment: It feels like the event could trigger a method on the data context of the item directly instead of triggering a method on the Window or ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking solution in MVVM pattern

**Edit**: Add a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity dll (which is system defined if Blend or VS2015 installed)

then add following namespace `xmlns:i="schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity‌​"`

// xaml file

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

// viewmodel (MyItem class)

```
  public void WhenMouseMove()
        {
            //Do stuff
            Console.WriteLine(Name);
        }

        private RelayCommand _MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand;
        public RelayCommand MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand == null)
                {
                    _MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(WhenMouseMove);
                }
                return _MouseHoveredItemChangedCommand;
            }
        }
```

// RelayCommand class

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
        {
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
            {
                add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
                remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
            }
            private Action methodToExecute;
            private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
            public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
            {
                this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
                this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
            }
            public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
                : this(methodToExecute, null)
            {
            }
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
                    return result;
                }
            }
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably works but I can't seem to be able to include interactions which I guess is needed for this code

Comment: Add a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity dll (which is system defined if Blend or VS2015 installed)

then add following namespace
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"